# Is it possible to list the avaiable JNDI datasources?

Tags: jdbc, datasource, jndi

Is it possible to list the avaiable JNDI datasources for the current application? If yes, how can I do this.

Comment: for a web application?

Comment: if yes in what application server?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy The best will be application server independent. It is for a library. But first we need it for WebSphere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code to try in a Servlet:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        InitialContext ictx = new InitialContext();
        Context ctx = (Context) ictx.lookup("java:");
        out.println("java: = " + ctx.getClass().getName());
        printContext(out, ctx, 1);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new ServletException(exc);
    }
}

private void printContext(PrintWriter out, Context ctx, int indent) throws ServletException, IOException, NamingException {
    NamingEnumeration en = ctx.listBindings("");
    while (en.hasMore()) {
        Binding b = (Binding) en.next();
        char[] tabs = new char[indent];
        Arrays.fill(tabs, '\t');
        out.println(new String(tabs) + b.getName() + " = " + b.getClassName());
        try {
            if (b.getObject() instanceof Context) {
                printContext(out, (Context) b.getObject(), indent + 1);
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ServletException(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Try it out and let me know if it works